# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, the value gets to null after brackets?

Tags: c#

so i have assigned the properties to a recipe at the start of program, but after the window ends, i cannot refer to this later, because the value of strawberryrecipe.type is now null. (EDIT: so all i had to do was remove "Recipe" in Recipe strawberryrecipe = new Recipe(); since i already put it as Recipe in class level i guess)

```
public partial class Production_Optimization_Window : Window
{
    Ingredient strawberry;
    Recipe strawberryrecipe;



    public Production_Optimization_Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       Recipe strawberryrecipe = new Recipe();
       strawberryrecipe.Type = "asd";
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(strawberryrecipe.Type);  //Here i get the error, and blueberry recipe.type = null.
    }
```

Comment: There are hundreds of question on this. Have you searched why it's happening

Comment: edited it back to strawberry, sorry :) it's because i have a lot of recipes declared, just removed for simplicity in this thread

Comment: Somewhere in your class, `strawberryrecipe.Type` sets back to null

Comment: This is where it's useful to provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - so you can work on it, check that it's still showing the error, then copy and paste it straight into SO without any other changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it in two scopes... You want to remove the local scope and end up with this:

```
public partial class Production_Optimization_Window : Window
{
    Ingredient strawberry;
    Recipe strawberryrecipe;

    public Production_Optimization_Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // This will use the field "strawberryrecipe"
        strawberryrecipe = new Recipe();
        strawberryrecipe.Type = "asd";
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(strawberryrecipe.Type);
    }
}
```

Also, I have renamed `blueberryrecipe` to `strawberryrecipe` as you didn't make any reference to that in your code before the MessageBox?

Comment: And it's strawberries, not blueberries :)

Comment: Yes, was a work in progress! :-) Hopefully that will help OP understand. Thanks for the notes though.

Comment: Thank you very much Belogix, so the error was just "Recipe" in 
Recipe strawberryrecipe = new Recipe(); that should not have been there.

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned instance of `Recipe` to `strawberryrecipe` variable in constructor, but trying to use `blueberryrecipe` variable that is unassigned.

So in `Button_Click` method `blueberryrecipe` is `null` - that's why you're getting exception when trying to access its field.

In fact, your code even should not compile since there is no `blueberryrecipe` variable declaration anywhere in your code at all.

Comment: There's no such thing as "an instance of strawberry recipe" or "an instance of blueberryrecipe". The OP has created an instance of `Recipe`, and assigned a reference to that new instance to a local variable called `strawberryrecipe`. It's important to differentiate between variables, objects, references and types.

Comment: @JonSkeet reasonable, thank you. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: actually the error was just the "Recipe" in Recipe strawberryrecipe = new Recipe();